# C++ giving weird answers with large numbers (afaik not overflow)

Tags: c++, numbers

I was writing a small program to compare speed between CPP and Matlab, and I noticed I was getting the wrong answer when working with large numbers.

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"



int main()
{       

    clock_t t = clock();

    long x = 1000000;

    long sum = 0;    

    for (long i = 1;i <= x;i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }

    t = clock() - t;

    printf("It took %d ms, sum equals=",t);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

100 000 returns the right answer, but above 1000 0000 does not. Anyone have an idea what's going on? I can't imagine the problem being overflow because the numbers involved are simply not that big (correct answer is 5e9).

Comment: why you are not  using large number for large computations? use long long or int64, look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Use [`std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max), to check what's the biggest `long` that can be represented on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is overflow. 5e9 is 5'000'000'000, but the largest number a 32-bit signed integer (long on 32-bit platforms, and on 64-bit Windows; it's 64-bit on 64-bit Linux) can hold is 2'147'483'648.

Comment: damn, im an idiot; misread this table, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/, thought long was 2^63, never knew long long existed

Answer (score 0):

I gave your Programm a test run and it returned the right answer (compared with wolfram alpha). So there isn't an error in the code I would say.

EDIT: run on a 64bit machine, so you may use a 32bit and got the overflow like told in the answer above.